# Can the standard Riemannian metric of $S^n$ be realized as the restriction of certain metric on $T S^n$?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

**Edit:** According to  interesting  comment  of  Thomas  Rot to the  previous  version of  the  question, we  revise  the  question as follows:

First  note that  if  a  manifold  $M$  is  a  parallelizable  manifold , then it gets  a  natural  Riemannian metric which is  independent of the  base point $x\in M$.In  fact $TM \simeq M \times \mathbb{R}^n$ enable  us  to carry the  standard Euclidean inner  product  to each  fiber of  $TM$. In the  following question we apply this  obvious fact to  $M=TS^n$ as follows:

It is  well known that the  tangent  bundle  $TS^n$ of  $S^n$  is a parallelizable manifold, then once we  fix  a  trivialization for  its  tangent  bundle(The tangent  bundle  of  $TS^n$),   $TS^n$ gets s a natural Riemannian metric, the Euclidean one along each fiber of its tangent bundle.
Now we can restrict this metric on $T S^n$ to the zero section $S^n$.

> Is there  a  trivialization of  $TS^n$   for  which the  corresponding  restricted metric coincide  to the standard metric of $S^n$?

Comment: "The euclidean one along each fiber" depends on the trivialisation you choose, hence there is no such natural one.

Comment: @ThomasRot Yes you are right. We should fix a trivialization. I am not aware of a canonical one.Is there any? On the other hand it would be possible that all trivialization leads to isometric metrics on $S^n$, so the comparison of the restricted metric with the standard one (up to isometry) is  a well defined question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You describe only a fiber metric on $TS^n$, an inner product on each fiber, but not a Riemannian metric on the total space. If you consider the metric induced from the embedding $Ti:TS^n \to T\mathbb R^{n+1} = \mathbb R^{n+1}\times \mathbb R^{n+1}$ (where $i:S^n\to \mathbb R^{n+1}$), then the answer is yes.

## Further explanation:

$i:S^n\subset\mathbb R^{n+1}$ is the standard embedding. The image of  the tangent mapping $Ti$ consists of all $(x,\xi)\in \mathbb R^{n+1}\times \mathbb R^{n+1}$ such that $|x|=1$ and $\langle x,\xi\rangle = 0$. The Riemannian metric induced on $TS^n$ from the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb R^{n+1}\times \mathbb R^{n+1}$ is Euclidean on each fiber $T_xS^n$ (fix $x$), and the metric on the zero section is the usual one (set $\xi=0$).

Comment: Dear Prof. Michor thank you for your answer. But I search for a Riemannian metric on $TS^n$. Every parallelizable manifold $M$ admit a Riemanian metric with constant coefficient, independent of base point $x\in M$.

Comment: @Ali Taghavi: This is a Riemannian metric on $TS^n$, it is the Euclidean one on each fiber as you specified, and it has the property you asked for: The embedding of the 0-section is an isometric immersion.

Comment: I do not understand the first 3 lines of your answer.May I ask you to explain about that?

Comment: I am not sure that $S^n$ is parallelizable except $n=1,3,7$; check e.g., $S^2$ (say, for non-zero section). Parallelization is just diffeomorphism $TM \to M\times R^n$, it does not provide any immersion into, say $R^N$; so you have to chose one. And of course taking on the product $M\times R^n$ a product metric you always have zero section $M\times 0$ isometric to $M^n$.

Comment: Dear Prof. Michor thanks again for your attention to my question and further explanation.